# Entity Framework 7 add class library error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I added to the Entity Framework class library annex 7 commander. But "project.json" file "dependencies" in part I encounter the following error.

> The dependecy EntityFramework.Commands 7.00-rc1-final in project ProLine.Sl does not support framework .NetPlatform,Version=v5.4.

```
   {
     "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-*",
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        "ProLine.Core": "1.0.0-*"

      },
      "commands": {
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
      },
```

Entity Framework 7 project I added ProLine.Bl

The project is a multi-layered project

ProLine  => Web Layer

ProLine.Sl => Service Layer

ProLine.Bl => Data Access Layer (Entity Framework 7 class library is loaded.)

ProLine.Core => Data Objects Layer

ProLine.Model => Model Layer

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add `EntityFramework.Commands` to ProLine.BI

http://www.bricelam.net/2014/09/14/migrations-on-k.html